# Кнопка не работает

Tags: javascript

Почему кнопка не работает? Ошибок в консоль не выводит

```js
function init() {
  var fireButton = document.getElementById('#fireButton');
  fireButton.onclick = handleFireButton;
}

function handleFireButton() {
  var guessInput = document.getElementById('#guessInput');
  var guess = guessInput.value;
  controller.processGuess(guess);
  guessInput.value = "";
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="guessInput" placeholder="A0">
  <input type="button" id="fireButton" value="Fire!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- в `getElementById` не надо указывать знак решетки `#`;
- `init` в конце надо вызвать;

```js
function init() {
  var fireButton = document.getElementById('fireButton');
  fireButton.onclick = handleFireButton;
}

function handleFireButton() {
  var guessInput = document.getElementById('guessInput');
  var guess = guessInput.value;
//вставьте ваш код
  alert(guess)
}
//вызываем инит
init()
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="guessInput" placeholder="A0">
  <input type="button" id="fireButton" value="Fire!">
</form>
```

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо!